# How to read 2 decimal places without round in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

Sample Code

```
<cfset b = 5.5566>
<cfset c = numberFormat(b,"9.99")>
<cfdump var="#c#">
```

I need c= 5.55 only. How can I do this ,because numberFormat rounds the number?

Comment: Use string functions.  Find() will give you the position of the decimal point.  len() gives you the total number of characters.  Left() allows you to truncate.

Comment: There no direct numeric function available to truncate decimal places?

Comment: If you don't want string functions, you can use [int](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/int) to round down - i.e. `int(b*100)/100` or `int(b*10^x)/10^x` where x is number of decimal places.

Comment: Truncating without rounding is too unusual for a native function to be available.  In fact, if I was asked to do it, I'd ask the customer if he was sure about that request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Dan points out, truncating / rounding down is an uncommon scenario, and you should double-check this is what the client actually wants, and why they want it (i.e. they might *think* they want it but have incorrect reasoning.)

If there is a valid reason to do it, the easiest way is probably to use the [**int**](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/int) function - equivalent to "floor" in some languages - it will round numbers down to the next integer, so `1.999` becomes `1`.
<sub>(If negative numbers are a factor, consider instead [**fix**](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/fix) which rounds towards the smaller integer, that is, towards zero.)</sub>

Since you want two decimal places, you would use it like this:

```
c = int(b*100)/100
```

Where the mulitply and divide by 100 is what provides the two decimal places.

For an arbitrary number of decimal places, you can replace the 100s with 10<sup>dp</sup> - where dp is the number of decimal places, for example:

```
c = int(b*10^dp)/10^dp
```

If you're doing that, it's probably worth wrapping it in a suitably named function so it's more readable. *(And if necessary adding a comment to explain why you're rounding down rather than the more common rounding to nearest value.)*

For the sake of showing another way, this could also be solved with a regex replace:

```
c = b.replaceAll('(?<=\.\d\d)\d+$','')
```

That removes all digits that are preceeded by the decimal place and two digits, until the end of string.

However, this is mentioned solely for educational purposes - the int solution is going to be more efficient.

Comment: I would have upvoted this twice if poss: once for the answer, and once for encouraging @Deepak to make sure his requirements are correct here.